# How to move to Markdown ATX-style headers?

Tags: cursor-movement, filetype-markdown, navigation, plugin-vim-pandoc, plugin-vim-markdown

How can I move (navigate) between [Markdown ATX-style headers](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header)?

The Vim plugin https://github.com/gbgar/pandoc-sections.vim does so using the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys, but only when there is no space between the opening `#` hashes and the header text.

Unfortunately, above plugin is no longer maintained and the now more common space between the opening `#` hashes and the header text is not supported.

The solution could be as easy as forking the plugin and extending the regex's in https://github.com/gbgar/pandoc-sections.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/pandoc/pandoc-sections.vim
However, my attempts at successfully extending the regex's were in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked plugin gives the following regexs (modified to only include `#`-relevant parts):

```
^\s*#\a.*\n
^\s*#\{2,6}.*\n
```

The first requires an alphabetic character (`/\a`) after the `#`; the second does not (`.*`). So you could take at least the function `PandocSectionMovement` and keybindings if you modify the first regex to

```
^\s*#.*\n
```

Do be warned that this might catch comments in embedded code, like in the following snippet of markdown:

````
```bash
# this is a comment
```
````

You *might* be able to work-around that by passing `{skip}` to `search` like

```
" 0 stopline, timeout is like not passing a value
call search(s:movpattern, l:sflag, 0, 0,
      \ {-> synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0)->synIDattr('name') !~# 'markdownH\d'})
```

At, least, this worked for me on a [test file with sh-like comments](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thanks! Removing all instances of `\a` indeed did the trick. For those interested, a [**working fork of the original plugin**](https://github.com/stroobandt/pandoc-sections.vim) is now available.